# Движение объекта в определенном радиусе в сторону клика

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Приветствую.  Есть круг(картинка), внутри круга - круг поменьше. Нужно, чтоб при нажатии(и движении пальцем по экрану), внутренний круг двигался в сторону клика, но не выходил за пределы большего круга. Типа tochpad в libgdx, но там реагирует на клик только внутри круга.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй переопределить метод `hit` класса `Touchpad` следующим образом:

```
@Override
public Actor hit (float x, float y, boolean touchable) {
    return this;
}
```

Comment: БИНГО! Немного пошаманил и получилось. Спасибо!